# Create a private EKEvent in iOS

Tags: ios, ekevent, ekeventstore

I know how to create a `EKEvent` and add it to device calendar, Now I have a use case, where if I share a calendar with my friend, I dont want those events set by my app, to appear on sharedCalendar. In short, can we create a private `EKEvent`, which is visible only to owner of the calendar.

This feature is available in andriod,

```
CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE
```

I read docs for `EKEvent`, I didnt find any reference, if anybody knows, if such thing is possible, let m know.

Comment: you just need to create an own calendar which is not visible or available in the Calendar app, and you can access to that special calendar and its events from the app only.

Comment: So platform, doesnt provide any such option?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Create another calendar for that purpose.